# Maven-release plugin: Branch without snapshot in version

Tags: maven, branch, maven-release-plugin

I want to automate our branching process and for that i am using maven-release-plugin.
Following command is used for branching:

```
 mvn --batch-mode release:branch -DupdateBranchVersions=true 
-DupdateWorkingCopyVersions=$MoveWorkingCopyToNextVersion 
-DautoVersionSubmodules=true -Darguments="-DskipTests" 
-DreleaseVersion=$BranchVersion -DbranchName=$BranchVersion 
-DscmCommentPrefix=$ReleaseJira: 
-Dusername=$BuildUser -Dpassword=$BuildUserPassword
```

My problem is that with above command version of pom created in branch is "BranchVersion-SNAPSHOT" while i want pom version in branch should be "BranchVersion" i.e. it should not contain snapshot.

I know this is not standard approach but our current release process will not work if branch contains "SNAPSHOT".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide your pom?

Comment: I had the same problem and after a lot of frustrating hours I ended up  branching manually. I think the release plugin is kind of buggy concnernig the branch goal...

Comment: Have you tried with `updateVersionsToSnapshot=false`?

Comment: @AleksandrM: I tried with updateVersionsToSnapshot=false but its still setting -SNAPSHOT version. Do you have any example of this?

Comment: Actually no. But you can look in the source code why this parameter isn't working. http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/release/trunk/maven-release-plugin/.

Comment: They have a ticket for the bug they just never fixed it. 
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-959

Answer (score 1):

If you don't get updateVersionsToSnapshot working could you use the versions plugin afterwards to set the version on the Pom

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html

Comment: You are right but this option is not feasible for me because i want to create a hudson job for branching and can't execute 2 maven commands in same hudson job.

Comment: I would probably just write a plugin which does the branching and setting the correct version in one mojo call. I've done this kind of thing and it works well.